# vscode rust autocomplete is incomplete

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust

I was watching a youtube video tutorial and he was using jetbrains

And this is what is seen on his autocomplete :
[intellij image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAoni.png)

This is what I see in my VSCode autocomplete:
[my vscode image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCP2U.png)

He has more options than i do.

I have "Rust for Visual Studio Code" extension installed

How do I show more options ?

Comment: From what I understand, the IntelliJ plugin and VS Code extension are completely independent; you shouldn't expect them to have identical features.

Comment: You can try rust-analyzer extension in vscode. https://rust-analyzer.github.io/

Comment: @AsceticBear, On its webpage it says "Note the extension may cause conflicts with the official Rust extension. It is recommended to disable the Rust extension when using the rust-analyzer extension."I did enable it anyway and now getting autocomplete like jetbrains. thank you

Answer (score 2):

The [Rust Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rust-lang.rust) is lacking some autocompletion and is pretty slow. [rust-analyzer](https://rust-analyzer.github.io/) is much faster and provides better autocompletion.